# Freedom of Movement and its interpretation

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I was reading [Freedom of Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/freedom-of-movement) and I have a question about how its worded, specifically the line that follows:

> The subject automatically succeeds on any combat maneuver checks and Escape Artist checks made to escape a grapple or a pin.

Reading this it can be understood two different ways.

1. Both the CMB checks and Escape Artist checks are for escaping a grapple/pin, I suspect this is the intended reading.
2. Its taken as two separate things, "The subject automatically succeeds on any combat maneuver checks" and "Escape Artist checks made to escape a grapple or a pin"

Mostly I ask because taking the second option seems overpowered and also out of line for how the spell feels like it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freedom of movement essentially makes the person upon whom it is affecting immune to grapples from any source. Any attempts to impede your movement or bind you such as Hold Person, Web, Solid Fog, or Black Tentacles automatically fails to affect you.

However it is worth noting that these effects only take place after the spell is cast. If you get grappled prior to actually casting Freedom of Movement and you don't have Freedom of movement prepared with Still spell / Eschew materials you're going to be in for a rather rude awakening unless you have some kind of Contingency / Grapple in place.

Answer (score 0):

You only automatically succeed on checks to **escape a grapple or a pin**.
Be it a CMB grapple check to escape, or a Escape Artist check to escape.